# Django, error in form submission, Django form unable to take entered text

Tags: django

The code is to receive a text and search database, below code work well

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'search:search' %}">
    <input placeholder="Search">
    <button  type="submit">{% trans "Search" %}</button>
</form>
```

However I decided to change UI, but after form submission, Django does not getting entered text

```
<form class="example" method="GET" action="{% url 'search:search' %}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
```

I am using Django Oscar library, https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/templates/oscar/partials/search.html

Comment: Please show your view for this page.

Comment: Using Django Oscar,don't know where it is

Comment: Your first snippet would also not work you don't even set the name attribute there. Looking at the link you provide your inputs name attribute should be `q`, i.e. `<input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="q">`. The name attribute is very important in form inputs as that is what the server uses to find the data that is posted (In this case the view written in Oscar expects an input with the name `q`).

Comment: Your suggestion seems worked well, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="example" method="GET" action="{% url 'search:search' %}">
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
```